# how does a smart pool identifies the valid block in ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-classic, mining-pools

I have been reading this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/019.pdf.

To my understanding, the miners send the shares in batches and later the smart pool verifies the shares with sampling with augmented merkel trees.
after the shares are verified, the shares are placed in verclaim sets.

Now what do i don't get is the smart pool needs to identify the valid block from  the shares and broadcast to the network. How does the smart pool find the valid block?? moreover doesnot the smartpool only have the augmented merkel root instead of whole the shares from all the miners??

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but still..

A miner that finds a valid share that is also a valid block will broadcast the block immediately to the network. SmartPool will receive the reward of the block and will pay the miners.
The claim is only used to pay the miner according their effort.